# Omit the subject after a conjunction in negative sentence?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, negation

I suppose these two sentences are equivalent:

> I did A and I did B.
>
> I did A and B.

So in the case of

> I didn't do A, but I did B.

Can I use:

> I didn't do A but B(past tense).

Or:

> I did B but not A.

?

Comment: Yes, you can, and I would use that construction.  A comma helps the reader: I didn't do A, but B. Same with A, but not B.

Comment: All are fine and equivalent except the last negative sentence which differs in meaning. If you say **I did B, not A**, the meaning will also be the same.

Comment: Thank you, both. As @mahmudkoya said I made a mistake in the last sentence.

Comment: i'd go for 'i did not A but B'

Comment: Incidentally, you can replace *but* with a comma in your last example: *I did B, not A*.